# Does Spark support lifecycle hook functions?

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, is it possible to register certain code to run within certain parts of the job lifecycle - say when a new executor starts, when an executor shuts down, when a new partition is about to be processed...etc?

Currently there are methods like `forEachPartition` or `forEachRdd` but you have to infer their execution context implicitly, and any hook code has to be written inline rather than registered separately.

Comment: How about creating a SparkListener? Several similar question on SO, for example [How to programmatically get information about executors in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526301/how-to-programmatically-get-information-about-executors-in-pyspark)

Comment: Thanks. SparkListener seems to fit the bill. The docs page for that shows a lot of event hooks: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html

Comment: Not "a lot", ALL events arriving into Spark event queue :)