# How to find out when Spark Application has any memory/disk spills without checking Spark UI

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-ui

My Environment:

- Databricks 10.4
- Pyspark

I'm looking into Spark performance and looking specifically into memory/disk spills that are available in Spark UI - Stage section.

What I want to achieve is to get notified if my job had spills.

I have found something below but I'm not sure how it works:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/SpillListener.html

I want to find a smart way where major spills are rather than going though all the jobs/stages manually.

ideally, I want to find spills programmatically using pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SpillListener` class as shown below,

```
spillListener = spark._jvm.org.apache.spark.SpillListener()
print(spillListener.numSpilledStages())
```

If you need more details, you have to  extend that class and override the methods.

But, I think we can't add custom listeners directly on PySpark we have to do it via Scala. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082957/how-to-add-a-sparklistener-from-pyspark-in-python).

You can refer this [page](https://www.databricks.training/spark-ui-simulator/experiment-6518/v002-S/index.html) to see how we can implement SpillListener in scala.